# UITextField missing copy|paste menu after selectall

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

In my project, I have several `UITextFields` in different views, such as `UITableviewcell` contains `UITextfield`, in a simple view, and so on.

I have a problem in my project. When I touch the `UItextfield`, input some text, and then do a longclick, it will show a menu select|selectall. When I click select, all the text is selected, but after selectall, it can't show the copy|paste menu. Why?

This phenomena does not always appear. Does anyone know what could cause this?

Comment: Yes this happens for me too. But nothing to worry. Its just a default feature of the textfield.

Comment: i don't think so ,it the default feature of the textfield ,becaues in the other app ,such as app store,it almost not appeared ,but in my app ,it always appears,i don't know why .Now my version is 1.3,but in 1.2 ,nothing happy.just 1.3.why

Comment: not feature ,i think it's a bug